# Two-dimensional array filled with random 0and1 php

Tags: php, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array, random

I want to generate 2d array with 20 cols and 20 rows with random numbers 0 and 1 and print it into table.  Array should represent a table, when it is 0 that there is nothing on the table and when the value is 1 there is something on the table.

but when i try this:

```
public $md_pole =array([0],[19]) ;
        public function vypln($md_pole)
        {

            $md_pole = range(0, 1);
            srand((double)microtime() * 1000000);    ?>
                        <body>
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                            <?php
                            for ($col = 0; $col <= 19; $col++) { shuffle($md_pole);
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <?php for ($row = 0; $row <= 19; $row++) {shuffle($md_pole); ?>
                                        <td><?php echo $md_pole[$row];?></td>
                                    <?php  } ?>
                                </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </body>
                        <?php
                    }
```

Then it is with two cols and 19.
Could someone help me with it?

Comment: your $md_posl is an array of dimension of 2X1

Comment: If I understand you right - why can't you use just `rand(0,1)` instead of `$md_pole[$row]` in line 19? Here's a working example: http://ideone.com/wCiFaV

Comment: @Picard thank you this works perfect